# What is the best way (in terms of the accuracy of the result) to solve a linear system?

Tags: c++11, linear-algebra

What is the best way (in terms of the accuracy of the result) to solve a linear system?. Is it using iterative methods  (like conjugate gradient...) or decomposition methods (like SVD or LU)?

If you can recommend any solver in C++.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use the LAPACK bindings of `eigen` for ?GESVX routine.

Answer (score 1):

In numerical methods there is usually no best way to do anything. If there had been the best algorithm to solve a linear system, everyone would've been using it. Direct and iterative methods are somewhat orthogonal to each other: direct methods are useful when the system size is small and you need accurate solution, iterative methods can be used for much larger systems and when you can tolerate a certain error. The choice of a linear solver also depends on the type of a system matrix, dense or sparse, and its properties (symmetry, positive-definiteness, etc.).

There are many linear solvers available in C++. Take a look, for example, at [Intel MKL library](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl). It is free now.